# ValueError: server must be a Flask app or a boolean

Tags: django, plotly-dash

I'm trying to work through the simplest dashboard example in the django-plotly-dash [documentation](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/django-plotly-dash/latest/django-plotly-dash.pdf), but I'm consistently getting the ValueError above.

For the code below, assume the django project name is **django_project** and the django app name is **dashboard**.

My ROOT_URLCONF at **django_project/urls.py** has the following relevant code:

```py
import dashboard.dash_app
from dashboard.views import test_view

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('dashboard/', test_view, name='test_view'),
    path('django_plotly_dash/', include('django_plotly_dash.urls')),
]
```

My dashboard app view, located at **dashboard/views.py** is as follows:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

def test_view(request):
    return render(request, 'dashboard/main.html')
```

The **main.html** template is as follows:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

def test_view(request):
    return render(request, 'dashboard/main.html')
```

```
{% load plotly_dash %}

{% plotly_app name="SimpleExample" %}
```

Finally, the DjangoDash app instance is created in a file called **dashboard/dash_app.py**.  As shown earlier, this module is imported in django_project/urls.py, as above.  Code is as follows:

```py
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

from django_plotly_dash import DjangoDash

app = DjangoDash('SimpleExample')

app.layout = ...

@app.callback(...)
def callback_color(...):
    ...
```

During the debugging process, the only other seemingly relevant information that I have is that the **base_pathname** is '/django_plotly_dash/app/SimpleExample/'

Any other ideas?

Comment: can you post the traceback please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the recent update to Dash version 1.0 on 2019-06-20. The Dash class now checks to ensure that `server` is either boolean or an instance of Flask. Since django plotly_dash uses it's own PseudoFlask object, it fails this check and it is incompatible with Dash 1.0 and will need to be updated for use with the current Dash version.

Comment: Thanks.  This was the root of the issue.  Using Dash 0.43.0 solved the issue for me as well.

Comment: v0.9.13 of django-plotly-dash has just been released; this has a fix for the recent Dash change.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem today. Using an older version of Dash (0.43.0) solved it for me.